# Operator overloading in header files and in the cpp files

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I got an error, when I am trying to overload an operator.

My header file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef HALLGATO_H
#define HALLGATO_H

class Hallgato {
    private:
        char* nev;
        char* EHA;
        int h_azon;
        unsigned int kepesseg;
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H);
};
#endif
```

My cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Hallgato.h"
using namespace std;

    ostream& Hallgato::operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H) {
        output << "Nev: " << H.nev << " EHA: " << H.EHA << " Azonosito: " << H.h_azon << " Kepesseg: " << H.kepesseg << endl;
        return output;
    }
};
```

In my .cpp file, when I want to define the overloaded operator `<<`, I got an error. Why?

Comment: Hi B.J, can you add the error message you get?

Comment: You appear to have extra `}` in your file...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The operator is not a member of the class, it is a friend so

```
 ostream& Hallgato::operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H) {
```

should be

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H) {
```

also to be able to use the operator from other files you should add a prototype into the header file.

The header file would become this

**hallgato.h**

```
#ifndef HALLGATO_H
#define HALLGATO_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Hallgato {
    private:
        char* nev;
        char* EHA;
        int h_azon;
        unsigned int kepesseg;
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Hallgato& H);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Hallgato& H);

#endif /* End of HALLGATO_H */
```

Somewhere in a ".cpp" file you would implement the operator function, you can also do it in the header file but then you would have to recompile often with some compilers.

**hallgato.cpp**

```
#include "hallgato.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Hallgato& H) 
{
   /* Some operator logic here */
}
```

NOTE:
When you modify header files, many compilers usually do not re-include them in your `.cpp` files. This is done to avoid unnecessary recompilation. To force a re-include, you have to make some modifications(delete empty line) to the source files which include those headers or force recompilation in your compiler/IDE.

Comment: Rebuild all the files again if you are using Dev-C++ 5.11 (Windows x64). Took my hour on this.

Answer (score 3):

In header file you declared friend method for class

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H);
```

this method shoud be defined (in cpp) without `Hallgato::`

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Hallgato& H)
```

because this method is not part of Hallgato class.